# ASP .NET WebForms siteMap strange case Expecting end tag </siteMap

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sitemap

I'm just currently doing some mini tasks as for my study subject in WebForms technology. I haven't used Web Forms earlier, and now I've just faced quite strange problem with siteMap.

What I was going to achieve was to just expand the navigation bar menu into lower level menu while mouse hovered, and I don't really know why it just works for the first menu (currently it looks like these)

[image]

The strange part is that everytime when I try to expand other navigation menu parent Items I still receive an error like this saying:

```
    Expecting end tag </siteMap>
```

and this is surely compared with siteMapNode tag, just don't really know why does it happen to me? Could You please check if my xml tree bellow looks fine for this case?

I would be glad for any directions, Thanks for Your support! :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Home" description="">
      <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home" description="Strona główna" />
      <siteMapNode url="Uslugi.aspx" title="Nasze usługi" description="Poznaj Nasze usługi">
      <siteMapNode url ="About.aspx" title="O nas" description="Poznaj Nas"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url ="UniqueStuff.aspx" title="Wyróżnia Nas" description="Czym się różnimy od konkurencji?"></siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="Produkty.aspx" title="Produkty" description="Zapoznaj się z naszymi produktami" />
      <siteMapNode url ="Bestsellery.aspx" title="Bestsellery" description="Hity sprzedaży"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url ="Nowosci.aspx" title="Nowości" description="Outsourcing Page"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url ="Wyprzedaz.aspx" title="Wyprzedaż" 
       description="Pozycje przecenione"></siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
              <siteMapNode url="TrustUs.aspx" title="Zaufali Nam" 
            description="About Us Page" />
        </siteMapNode>**-------------------in THIS PLACE there is a red underline saying "<Expecting end tag </siteMap>**
                  </siteMap>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error

```
  <!-- the following tag closes itself -->
  <siteMapNode url="TrustUs.aspx" title="Zaufali Nam" description="About Us Page"/>
  </siteMapNode> <!-- Syntax Error tag above was already closed -->
</siteMap>
```

Because the you have a self-closing tag followed by a tag that would otherwise close it. That means the opening `<siteMap>` tag does not get paired with the closing one.

Your IDE should be showing this as an error.

Make sure you enable all validation options for HTML/WebForms in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks for hint, gonna check that today! : )

Comment: Worked perfect :)

Comment: Glad to hear that! Do try to setup some automatic validation. No one should edit XML/HTML/SGM without tool support, it is inhumane :p.

Comment: Will do that for sure :)